# How can I limit this statement to only do the distinction on the first column 'COMPANY_NAME' and not the other columns

Tags: sql, distinct

```
select DISTINCT(COMPANY_NAME) , COMPANY_CODE, CONTACT_NAME , PHONE_NUMBER 
FROM COMPANIES 
WHERE HAS_INVENTORY = 'T' 
AND STATUS = 'ON' 
AND CONTACT_NAME <> ' ' 
AND PHONE_NUMBER NOT LIKE '%N/A%' 
AND EMAIL_ADDRESS NOT LIKE '%@SOME_EMAIL.COM' 
ORDER BY COMPANY_NAME ASC
```

I need this code to return the above columns where the company name does not repeat itself.

Comment: `DISTINCT` always considers the **whole** record, not individual columns. Can you show some example output of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I think he asking how to ignore duplicate values on a specific field in the output of the query

Comment: @lrb: If you have to guess what is being asked, the question is unclear.

Comment: I apologize this is my first post, Irb was right I am trying to ignore duplicate values on a specific field (COMPANY_NAME)

Comment: Are you wanting to output NULL or '' for repeating COMPANY_NAME values similar to creating a report with groupings? Also, (without questioning why?) does your database allow for multiple contacts for the same COMPANY_NO in the same table?

Answer (score 0):

What dbms are you using?

If you are using postgres 8.4 forward you can do:

```
select distinct on (company_name)
    *
from table ....
```

On mssql, you would need to do a subquery, and then filter the outer result such as like this:

```
select *
from 
from (
    select COMPANY_NAME, COMPANY_CODE, CONTACT_NAME,PHONE_NUMBER 
       , row_number() over(partition by company_name order by /* however you want to order it */) row_id
    FROM COMPANIES 
    WHERE HAS_INVENTORY = 'T' 
    AND STATUS = 'ON' 
    AND CONTACT_NAME <> ' ' 
    AND PHONE_NUMBER NOT LIKE '%N/A%' 
    AND EMAIL_ADDRESS NOT LIKE '%@SOME_EMAIL.COM' 
    ORDER BY COMPANY_NAME ASC
    ) x
where row_id = 1
```

Kinda dirty, but that is the only way I have solved this before...

If you want distinct records for both COMPANY_NAME and CONTACT_NAME, then you would simply add BOTH columns under the "partition" section of the row_number() function.

Comment: That is the same as taking the first value of a group aggregated on COMPANY_NAME.  If (for whatever reason) there are several distinct  CONTACT_NAME's for a COMPANY_NAME then how do you know which one to take?

Comment: Thats where the "order by" clause comes into effect using the row_number() function. It will order by and will enumerate the rows starting from 1, 2, 3, etc. based on the order by for each distinct value in the column(s) specified in the "partition by" clause

Comment: However, if you are selecting where row_id =1 then when the same company name appears again with a different contact_name you will get row_id=2 but you will never see that contact due to your where clause.

Comment: I am not saying you are incorrect I may have misinterpreted the question. Your answer will return the first contact in natural order with the same COMPANY. It would seem each contact is being sought in the question.

Comment: Oh, I see. Well then one would have group by the company and then throw the other oclumns into an array. In postgres this is simple to do using the array_agg() function and then outside of that you put array_to_string([array],', '). But I am not sure the DBMS being used here. Or you could put in the "partition by" clause both the company_name and contact_name. Then it would give distinct rows on those two columsn. I updated the answer.